Ruby: Listen on TCPsocket for individual bytes (no CR/LF) and write to file
I'd like to write a server that listens on a given TCP port, captures incoming data and processes it one byte at a time (the amount of data coming in is minimal - a few kilobytes per hour)
For simplicity, I'd like to echo the ASCII code of the character received to the console. I have a working string-based implementation but don't know how to make the server process bytes immediately instead of waiting on a CR/LF.
Any help appreciated! I'm using Ruby 3.3.1
I tried to use data = socket.recvfrom(1000) but this still waits on a CR/LF as far as I can tell

Try using socket.getbyte. This returns the ascii code for the next received byte. You can then print the byte with Integer#chr.
socket.getbyte # => 104
socket.getbyte.chr # => "h"

You could then put this in a loop to print the incoming data to the console.
loop do
  puts socket.getbyte.chr
end


The loop you used is an infinite loop?
